# How to convert multiline string to data in swift 5.0?

Tags: ios, swift

In order to conform to post request body format i have to insert data with the next format :

```
id:12
nickname:Nikola
comment:asdasd
```

JSON Serialization wont do the job since it produces result with { } and ""

```
"{\"nickname\":\"Nikola\",\"comment\":\"asdasdasd\",\"id\":\"12\"}"
```

which are not valid in my case. If i use classic Data init it gives back string formatted to single line using \n which also doesnt work.

```
"blog_id:12\nnickname:Nikola \ncomment:asdasd"
```

The string i am using as input is :

```
"""
            id:\(id!)
            nickname:\(authorName)
            comment:\(commentContent)
"""
```

I need it to stay multiline and have multiline format when converted to data without any special chars.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't \n work?

Comment: `string.data(using: .utf8)` or `Data(string.utf8)`

Comment: Because my server/backend cant read it in this format with /n
Using data with .utf8 wont do the job